# Checked exception is invalid for this method in java Unit Test

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I'm trying to have one of my mocked objects throw a checked Exception when a particular method is called. i am getting below exception can some one help me please

### MSThread

```
              try {
                    if (command.equals("NEAT_TEST"))
                        url = nsReqUrl;
                    else if (command.equals("RETEST_FIBER"))
                        url = retestfiberUrl;
                    else
                        url = nsDirectTl1Url;
                    resultMsg = MSNeatServiceHandler.sendRequest(msg, url);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    s = e.toString();
                    if (exceptionCnt++ < _nsCmdMaxRetries) {
                        _logger.warn("Neat or Direct TL1 Service exception (attempt " + exceptionCnt + " of "
                                + (_nsCmdMaxRetries + 1) + ").. " + e);
                        resultMsg = MSNeatServiceHandler.sendRequest(msg, url);
                    } else {
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
```

### Test Class

```
@Test
    public void testMSThread_NeatTest3() throws Exception {
        String url = "";
        PowerMockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(MSNeatServiceHandler.sendRequest(msg,url));
        MSThread result = new MSThread(name, rh, buff, props);
        result.process(msg);
    }
```

### error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.lang.Exception
    at com.verizon.dtix.microsvcagent.MSThreadTest.testMSThread_NeatTest3(MSThreadTest.java:201)
```

Comment: Please show method signature of MSNeatServiceHandler.sendRequest(msg, url).

Comment: public static String sendRequest(MSMsg msg,String nsURI) throws DtixException

Comment: which line is **201** in the test? Please note that you call `sendRequest()` twice.

Comment: @diginoise  org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.verizon.dtix.microsvcagent.MSThreadTest.testMSThread_NeatTest3(MSThreadTest.java:204) when i debug this method individually